# How to clear selected items collection

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF Application with two `ComboBox`
When I select the first one the items related  to the first combobox will be populated on the second one

Here is my select Property

```
   public string SelectedApplication
    {
        set
        {
            if (_selectedApplication == value) return;
            this._selectedApplication = value;

            InitializeTransactionTypes();


        }
        get
        {
            return this._selectedApplication;
        }

    }
```

here i am checking a matching id between the two comboboxes to populate the second combobox items.

```
    ObservableCollection<TransactionTypeViewModel> _transTypeObsList = new ObservableCollection<TransactionTypeViewModel>();
       private void InitializeTransactionTypes()
    {
        if (_selectedApplication != null)
        {

              var getAppCode =
                ApplicationVModel.GetAllApplications()
                                 .FirstOrDefault(apps => apps.Name == _selectedApplication);

            var transTypeList = TransactionTypeVModel.GetAllViewModelTransTypes()
                                                     .Where(t => getAppCode != null && t.Id == getAppCode.Id);

            transactionTypes = new ObservableCollection<TransactionTypeViewModel>(transTypeList);

            NotifyPropertyChanged("TransactionTypes");
        }
    }
```

More information about methods:

List of VM mapped from List of Model

```
       public List<TransactionTypeViewModel> GetAllViewModelTransTypes()
    {
        TransactionTypeViewModels =   TransactionTypeModel.GetAllTransactionTypes().Select(transType => new TransactionTypeViewModel
        {
            Id = transType.Id,
            Name = transType.Name,


        })
    .ToList();
        return TransactionTypeViewModels;
    }
```

Lets say I select first combobox has {A,B,C,D} ...and the second combobox has  {A'1,A'2,A'3}, when I select item from first Combobox the second combobo keeps populating 
items. I wanted to show only {A'1 for A} {B'1 for B} ...etc but now what it does is  {A'1  A'1 A'1 ..... for A} {B'1 B'1 B'1 ....for B} for every select.

I want the previous selection to be cleared and display a new list per select. Thanks

Comment: Instead of recreating `_transTypeObsList` each time in `InitializeTransactionTypes` try to `Clear()` and `Add(...)` items one by one.

Comment: to be clear I don't know if this it the issue but you create your list to often. Instead `transactionTypes = new ObservableCollection<TransactionTypeViewModel>....` do something like `transactionTypes.Clear(); foreach(....) transactionTypes.Add(....)`

Comment: @dkozl Thanks that works for me ... I cleared and add for every iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum up comments. Instead of creating new `ObservableCollection` every time something changes reuse one that you already have and it will notify UI about changes. Your `InitializeTransactionTypes` should look something like this:

```
private void InitializeTransactionTypes()
{
  if (_selectedApplication != null)
  {
        var getAppCode =
          ApplicationVModel.GetAllApplications()
                           .FirstOrDefault(apps => apps.Name == _selectedApplication);

      transactionTypes.Clear();
      foreach(var transactionItem in TransactionTypeVModel.GetAllViewModelTransTypes().Where(t => getAppCode != null && t.Id == getAppCode.Id))
         transactionTypes.Add(transactionItem);
  }
}
```

and like this you should not have to notify about `TransactionTypes` changes any more